# How to explain KPSS test ( For test Stationarity) based on p value or KPSS value

Tags: time-series, arima

What would be Null and alternated hypothesis?

KPSS Test for Level Stationarity

data:  Returns
KPSS Level = 0.072065, Truncation lag parameter = 2, p-value =
0.1

Warning message:
In kpss.test(Returns) : p-value greater than printed p-value

Answer (score 0):

"In econometrics, Kwiatkowski–Phillips–Schmidt–Shin (KPSS) tests are used for testing a null hypothesis that an observable time series is stationary around a deterministic trend (i.e. trend-stationary) against the alternative of a unit root."

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KPSS_test

Comment: For the above result how to infer about the conclusion of the result

Answer (score 0):

TLDR: for kpss if p value is large (more than 1 percent or 5 percent ) series is stationary

I assume u have used R language to get this result . In kpss.test ,

H0 = series is stationary HA = series is not stationary

for the given values p value is 10% so we cannot reject H0 at both 5% and 1% significance levels